# Modular Arithmetic IFF Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: n ≡ 1 (mod 4) if and only if n ≡ 1 (mod 8) or n ≡ 5 (mod 8). I am a little confused on how to go about solving this problem. Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Start by applying the definition: $n \equiv 1$ (mod $4$) if and only if there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n-1=4k$ etc.

Comment: Rather than me trying to make another guess about what you tried or where you got stuck, you should tell us specifically.

Comment: $a\equiv 1(mod~4)\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in \mathbb{Z}~~~a=4k+1$

Comment: Now consider 2 cases: 1)$k$ is even and 2)$k$ is odd.

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1838182/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a\equiv 1(mod~4)\Longleftrightarrow \exists k\in \mathbb{Z}~~~a=4k+1$$
$k\in\mathbb{Z}\Longleftrightarrow$ 1)$k$ is even or 2)$k$ is odd.

1)$k=2j$ for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$

$$a=4k+1=4(2j)+1=8j+1\Longleftrightarrow a\equiv 1(mod~8)$$

2)$k=2j+1$ for some $j\in\mathbb{Z}$

$$a=4k+1=4(2j+1)+1=8j+5\Longleftrightarrow a\equiv 5(mod~8)$$

Therefore, $a\equiv 1(mod~4)\Longleftrightarrow a\equiv 1~or~5(mod~8)$.